# VSIX extension adding assembly reference to project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, vsix, visual-studio-addins

Im building an extension that should be able to add an assembly to a projects references

This assembly is included with the VSIX

Is including the assembly with the VSIX a good idea ?
How do I get the path to the assembly that was distributed with the VSIX ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the deployment directory of your VSIX extension, you can use the following code:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

Then just add your assembly name to this path.

Comment: Is this the recommended way to access assemblies bundled with a vsix?

Comment: I don't think there is official recommendation for assemblies bundling from MS.