# How to add resources to a Visual Studio Extension "Custom Tool"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have created a "Custom Tool" as a VS extension (VS2017), implementing (more or less) `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsSingleFileGenerator`.

The `Generate ()` method invokes an external code generator via `System.Diagnostics.Process`. That code generator creates multiple files from the given source, writing them directly to the project directory. (The tool does not create any "single file" output.)

All is fine and works as expected. The only disadvantage is that the "external code generator" is a separate entity at the moment. The custom tool has to locate it before it can invoke it.

What I want to do is to copy that external generator into the VSIX package and be able to invoke it there. The generator is a standalone .Net Core application, so basically a folder with lots of .dlls and an .exe.

How would I embed this folder into my VSIX package and how would I invoke it there? I couldn't find the slightest clue in the Visual Studio SDK doc, maybe because I don't know what I should be looking for.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51180046/include-whole-folder-in-vsix

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34974856/vsix-extension-adding-assembly-reference-to-project

Comment: In the end, I packed all the files in the standalone application folder into a zip file and added that to the VSIX package. On first invocation of the VS extension I unpack the zip. It's probably not the most elegant way but it works.